# How can you declare a class field that can be an object of one of a superclass's subclasses

Tags: java, oop, subclass, superclass

For example:

```java
public class Building{
   private int x;
   private int y;
   private int z;
}
public class Office extends Building{
   public void fx()
   public void fy()
   public Office(int x, int y, int z){
      x = x;
      y = y;
      z = z;
   }
}
public class School extends Building{
   public void fa()
   public void fb()
   public School(int x, int y, int z){
      x = x;
      y = y;
      z = z;
   }
}
```

So what should I place in the blank in the code below to refer to the subclasses of Building?
In other words, what should I place there such that building has a datatype that is Office or Building, whose datatype could be determined by a constructor?

```java
public class foo{
   private int dummy;
   private ____ building;

   public foo(int nd, ____ nb){
      dummy = nd;
      building = nb;
   }
}
public class mainF{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      foo object1 = new foo(1, new Office(1,2,3)); 
      foo obhect2 = new foo(1, new School(1,2,4)); 
   }
}
```

Comment: It's `Building`

Comment: if the field is called building, what do you think?

Comment: Did you have a look at generics, e.g. `Foo<T extends Building>`, `private T building` and `Foo(int nd, T nb)`? - don't forget to also add the generic type to the calls in your `main()` (and if you ask how to do that: read some tutorial on generics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Office and School are implementations of Building, then you could handle them like a Building object.

Maybe your question is not completely exposed?